# UNUserNotificationCenter didRecieve Response is not called if App is terminated

Tags: apple-push-notifications, swift3, ios10, xcode8, xcode8-beta3

UNUserNotificationCenter function is not called on clicking **Action Button** Chat in Notification after 3D Touch if App is not active(not even in Background or say has terminated). I used "attach to process by name" in Xcode to debug app when app was terminated. Here is the Code:

```
import UIKit
import Mixpanel
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        //setup mixpanel

        self.handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo(launchOptions: launchOptions)

        //ask for push notification perms
        return true
    }
```

When Notification Pop-up (Sent from MixPanel) this function is called first,

Call 1:

```
    func handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo(launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) {
        //Handle PushNotification when app is opened
    }
```

Then It goes here,

Call 2:

```
    //register for notification
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegister notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
            }
            center.delegate = self

            let actionChat = UNNotificationAction(identifier: Constants.ActionType.CHAT.rawValue, title: "Chat", options: [.foreground])
            let categoryOptions = UNNotificationCategoryOptions(rawValue: 0)
            let customerSupportCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: Constants.NotificationType.CUSTOMER_SUPPORT.rawValue, actions: [actionChat], intentIdentifiers: [], options: categoryOptions)
            center.setNotificationCategories([customerSupportCategory])
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
```

Call 3:

```
    // remote notification
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        ....Some Code....
    }
```

But **below function is not called**.
But if **app is running in background** then below function is called and **all works fine OTHERWISE App comes to foreground and chat does not after that**.

```
    // action buttons in enhanced Notification
    @available(iOS 10, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
        guard let action = Constants.ActionType(rawValue: response.actionIdentifier) else {
            completionHandler()
            return
        }
        switch action {
        case .CHAT:
            _ = self.handleRemoteUrl(NSURL(string: "chat") as? URL)
        default:
            _ = self.handleRemoteUrl(NSURL(string: "chat") as? URL)
        }
        completionHandler()
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
    }
}
```

This function is never called may be because it's depreciated in iOS 10 over userNotificationCenter(), not sure. Please explain this also..

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        ....Some Code....
    }
```

**I am using iPhone 6s iOS 10 as debugging device.**
**XCode 8 beta-3**

Comment: When app is not running or killed by user and notification is received then in such scenario you need to handle in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and check if app is opened via notification and act appropriately.

Answer (score 12):

From my own experimentation, receiving local notifications in Swift 3 & Xcode 8 are as follows:

**Conformance**

- Conform to `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

  ```
  class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate { .... }
  ```
- Register as Notification Center's delegate:

  ```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
      center.delegate = self

      return true
  }
  ```

**Delegate Methods**

- Respond to missed notifications (e.g. user viewing app when notification sent)

  ```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
      print(notification.request.content.userInfo)
  }
  ```
- Respond to actioned notifications (e.g. user opened notification)

  ```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void) {
      print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
  }
  ```

Comment: Yes, Actually I have done all these steps.. Later I found my mistake but have not added answer and expiation yet, So I just added **RegisterNotification.sharedHandler.registerFor3dTouchInNotification(appDelegate: self)** in **func handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo(launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?)** which register category every time we get notification, Not sure if it is correct way but It solved my problem..

Comment: This fixed it for me! Emphasis lies on registering the Notification center delegate directly in `appDidFinishLaunching` and no later.

Comment: Thank you! My issue was the appDidFinishLaunching as I have notification registration being handled after login. For the delegate I moved this to the appDidFinishLaunching and things are working well.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.1 Update

- Conform to UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
- Register as Notification Center's delegate:

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

- Delegate Methods

```swift
public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print(response.notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier)
}

public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print(notification.request.content.categoryIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: could you please tel me which method gets executed when your app is in background and receives notification?

Answer (score 0):

When app is not running or killed by user and notification is received then in such scenario you need to handle in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and check if app is opened via notification and act appropriately.

// Check if launched from notification

```
if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? [String: AnyObject] {
       notificationReceived(notification)
    }
```

Comment: not the case anymore with `UNUserNotificationCenter`, delegate is always called...

Comment: @HuguesBR could you please tel me which method gets executed when the app is in background and receives notiification?